# file not found when using header() in php7

Tags: php

When i update from php5.6 to php7.0.2 i`m getting error 'file not found'. In php5.6 all works fine, php.ini and other server settings the same.
This is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$this->name.'.xls"');//
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

While debug error appear after first and second line.
My server is Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with `file not found`?

Comment: in Cromium: This webpage is not available ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE, in Opera: remote server or file not found, in Firefox: file not found

Comment: Check the developer tools of chrome (networks tab). Also if you tell the client there is an attachment you need to output something. I don't see any outputs.

Comment: sorry, problem was in phpexcel, i just update it and now all works fine.